# How to manipulate the stdout of a NestJs app?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, stdout, knex.js

Is there any possibility to read and manipulate the stdout of a nestjs app? I want to filter this knexjs message:

> .returning() is not supported by sqlite3 and will not have any effect.

Add a listener to the stdout does not work.:

```
process.stdout.addListener('data', (data)=> {console.log('This is data: ', data)});
```

Additional I am not sure where to place it. If the listener is defined in a service (where I suspect the source), it does not output any messages anymore.